problem in printing colorful text in c programing
I wrote a program in C language and tried to print some texts in different colors, but I face such a problem:
My code:
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
printf("\033[1;32m sample.");
return 0;
}

But when I compile it in Windows 10 PowerShell with the following command:
gcc sample.c -o sample.exe
.\sample.exe

Instead of printing a colored text, the following text is printed:
←[1;32m sample.
Then I wrote such a program that only automatically compiled and executed the previous program:
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
system("gcc sample.c -o sample.exe");
system(".\\sample.exe");
return 0;
}

In this way, when I compile and run the first code with another program, everything works correctly and colored text is printed.

Based on the fundamental belief that one should never attempt to produce color by hard coding escape sequences that are specific to a terminal  (eg, instead of printf '\033[1;32m sample\n', one should query the terminfo database by writing tput setaf 2; echo sample)  I am guessing that powershell does not recognize the escape sequence as a command to alter the color, but that the system call is invoking a pseudo terminal that does recognize the escape sequence. The solution is to stop assuming that the string \033 has meaning to the device on which you are displaying text.

If you have tput and it works, use a hex dump to determine the characters that it writes to produce color, and try using that sequence in your C code.

Hi!  Have you done a deep dive into microsoft's Console Virtual Terminal Sequences knowledge base yet?   There is a nice C code sample at that URL too.
